# How can I customise newsletter template controller in magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to customise my magento newsletter template controller. I have already tried copy & pasting it from:

> core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/TemplateController.php

To:

> local/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/TemplateController.php

But it's still not working. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the controller.

You have to define the the things in config.xml

Refer these links:

http://technet.weblineindia.com/web/override-core-module-controllers-in-magento/
http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9754/trying-to-override-a-controller

It may help.

If you still didn't got it. Let me know in comment
i will edit my answer